# Define symbolic function in MATLAB within for-loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

Lets say I have the following vectors

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
b = [6 8 7 4 2 5];
```

Now I need to create a vector of symbolic function `f(x) = b.*x +a` where each `a` and `b` comes from the vectors `a` and `b` respectively.

```
for c = 1:length(a)
syms x
f(x) = b(1,c).*x + a(1,c);
fvector(1,c) = f;
end
```

However, this does not work, as it doesn't seem as if I'm able to create a symbolic function within a for-loop.

I need to create a symbolic function though as in the example above (not the exact same equation, but similar) and need to get the inverse function of each of these entries of the `fvector` vector.

Is there another way to do this that might work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly your goal is but if you gave a little more context and an example of an input and output that you expect that could help.

This code defines the symbolic function and computes the inverse function in a fairly general (and inefficient) way.

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
b = [6 8 7 4 2 5];

syms x y
for c = 1:length(a)
    f = b(c).*x + a(c);
    fvector(c) = f;
    finv(1,c) = subs(solve(f==y, x),y,x);
end
```

Output

```
fvector =

[ 6*x + 1, 8*x + 2, 7*x + 3, 4*x + 4, 2*x + 5, 5*x + 6]


finv =

[ x/6 - 1/6, x/8 - 1/4, x/7 - 3/7, x/4 - 1, x/2 - 5/2, x/5 - 6/5]
```